# Pig Latin Translator in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, pig-latin

I am a relatively new Python programmer and made a simple Pig Latin to English translator and vice versa. I would just like it if someone reviewed my code and see if anything can be done to make it more Pythonic or efficient.

```
from time import sleep

def main():
    to_piglatin = input("Do you want to translate something to piglatin[P], or to english[E]: ")

    while to_piglatin not in("p", "e"):
        to_piglatin = input("[P/E]")

    to_piglatin = ("e", "p").index(to_piglatin.lower())

    if to_piglatin:
        lang = "pig latin"
    else:
        lang = "english"
    question = "Enter a sentence to translate it into {}: ".format(lang)
    sentence = input(question)

    if not sentence.isalpha():
        print("Invalid input, please do not use numbers or punctuation marks")
        sleep(1)
        main()

    split_sentence = sentence.split()

    if to_piglatin:
        translated_sentence = [translate_to_piglatin(word) for word in split_sentence]
    else:
        translated_sentence = [translate_to_english(word) for word in split_sentence]

    translated_sentence = " ".join(translated_sentence)
    print(translated_sentence)
    input()
    return True

def translate_to_piglatin(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    list_word = list(word)
    list_word = [x.lower() for x in word]
    first_letter = list_word[0]
    last_letter = list_word[-1]

    if last_letter.isalpha() == False:
        list_word.remove(last_letter)
    if first_letter in vowels:
        list_word.append('y')
        list_word.append('a')
        list_word.append('y')
    else:
        list_word.remove(list_word[0])
        list_word.append(first_letter)
        list_word.append('a')
        list_word.append('y')

    translated_word = "".join(list_word)
    return translated_word

def translate_to_english(word):
    list_word = list(word)
    last_three_letters = list_word[-3:]
    last_three_letters = "".join(last_three_letters)

    if last_three_letters == 'yay':
        vowel = True
    else:
        vowel = False

    if vowel:
        for i in range(0,2):
            del list_word[-1]
    else:
        del list_word[-1]
        del list_word[-1]
        last_letter = list_word[-1]
        list_word.remove(last_letter)
        list_word.insert(0, last_letter)

    translated_word = "".join(list_word)
    return translated_word


main()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is this thing in Python called unpacking.

The idea being that you can assign at once in several variables all the values contained in a single sequence:

```
>>> example = (1, 2, 3)
>>> a, b, c = example
>>> print(a, b, c)
1 2 3
```

In fact, this mechanism works with any iterable, including strings. What's even better is that this [syntax got extended in Python 3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) to support assigning the remaining of the items into a single variable:

```
>>> a, *b, c = range(5)
>>> print(a, c)
0 4
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Now, let's make good use of it:

```
def translate_to_piglatin(word):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    first_letter, *remaining_letters = word.lower()

    if first_letter in vowels:
        return word + 'yay'
    else:
        return ''.join(remaining_letters) + first_letter + 'ay'
```

Here I removed the need for `first_letter, *inner_part, last_letter = word.lower()` because I assumed that `word` was not ill-formed. Since you check for `isalpha` in your `main`, you don't really need to do so in this function.

An other improvement would be to define `vowel` as a constant outside of this function.

Converting back can also easily make use of unpacking:

```
def translate_to_english(word):
    if word.endswith('yay'):
        return word[:-3]
    else:
        *remaining_letters, last_letter, a, y = word
        return last_letter + ''.join(remaining_letters)
```

In this case:

- I used a condition to enter the `if` rather than setting a boolean before;
- I used the slice syntax to extract out the last 3 characters directly.

In both cases I returned from within the `if` to simplify the logic and the variable management. Each branch needing its own kind of data structure to work with.

---

The last thing unpacking can help you with is the choice of language/transformation function. If you define, for each input letter, the name of the language and the associated transformation function in a tuple, you can extract them out easily:

```
CONVERSION_INFOS = {
    'e': ('english', translate_to_english),
    'p': ('pig latin', translate_to_piglatin),
}

def main():
    to_piglatin = input("Do you want to translate something to piglatin[P], or to english[E]: ").lower()

    while to_piglatin not in CONVERSION_INFOS:
        to_piglatin = input("[P/E]").lower()

    lang, translate = CONVERSION_INFOS[to_piglatin]

    sentence = input("Enter a sentence to translate it into {}: ".format(lang))

    if not sentence.isalpha():
        print("Invalid input, please do not use numbers or punctuation marks")
        sleep(1)
        main()

    translated_sentence = ' '.join(translate(word) for word in sentence.split())

    print(translated_sentence)
    input()
    return True
```

Note the use of `lower` on the first two `input`s so your `while` loop can break if the user input `'E'` or `'P'`.

I also merged some lines together to remove the intermediate variables you only use once and reduce the burden of understanding your code for the reader.

---

Lastly, you can improve the workflow of your program by making a correct use of return values. You don't need to return something at the end of a function in Python (meaning `return True` in `main` is unneccessary) when there is no associated meaning. However, we can make use of it:

- We return `True` if we correctly translated a sentence;
- We return `False` if we couldn't.

```
def main():
    to_piglatin = input("Do you want to translate something to piglatin[P], or to english[E]: ").lower()

    while to_piglatin not in CONVERSION_INFOS:
        to_piglatin = input("[P/E]").lower()

    lang, translate = CONVERSION_INFOS[to_piglatin]

    sentence = input("Enter a sentence to translate it into {}: ".format(lang))

    if not sentence.isalpha():
        print("Invalid input, please do not use numbers or punctuation marks")
        return False

    translated_sentence = ' '.join(translate(word) for word in sentence.split())

    print(translated_sentence)
    return True
```

This let you handle retries outside of the function:

```
while not main():
    pass  # or time.sleep(1) like you did, but it feels a bit unresponsive
```

You may also want to change the name of the function because it doesn't convey much meaning when calling it like that.

Comment: You've got my +1 for the first explanation. Nicely done

Answer (score 6):

### Variables and Naming

1. `to_piglatin` isn't a very good name. Try making it `language`
2. Speaking of `lang`, it doesn't look like you need it.
3. You only use question once. Just put it inside the call to input on the next line.
4. Change `list_word` to `word_list`. That sounds more natural.
5. The main method should be in something like this: (more pythonic)

   ```
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       main()
   ```

That is the standard for main methods, so if you, at a later date, decide to import you code from another file, the main method will not run and you can still use the translation functions.

### Code logic

1. Repeated calls to main can eventually overflow the stack trace (heh, stackoverflow).  Try making a Boolean that keeps track of the user has inputed a correct value, and put the entire input sequence in a while loop.
2. Why do you have an empty input?
3. Why does the main method return `True`? If anything (which it shouldn't, having a name like `main`), it should return the translated list.
4. `"the"` gets translated to `"hetay"` (not actual piglatin)
5. You don't have to enter an if statement to set a Boolean variable; just set it to the thing in the if.

That's about it for me. Other people will probably have better suggestions. Happy coding!

Comment: You can get code blocks inside bullet points by indenting a lot. It will look better and preserve newlines and indentation.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger well, I was stupid. I guess I skipped a line.